# Cannot remove whitespace with preg_replace with replacing other symbols

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a date format `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS` as a string from my database

What I want to do is to remove dashes and other hypens and whitepaces.

I have tried this below;

```
$date = preg_replace('/\s+-|:/', null, $row['acctstarttime']);

//also tried this
$date = preg_replace('/\s+-|:/', '', $row['acctstarttime']);
```

This does not work at all. I have solved it by using this below

```
$date = str_replace(' ', '', preg_replace('/-|:/', null, $row['acctstarttime']));
```

I don't think that is a good way to do it, so how could I remove spaces while removing other symbols such as `-`,`/`,`:` within only using `preg_replace`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the proper tools? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php and then http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php or even http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and then http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try this:

```
[-, \/:]
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/DffZNA/1)

PHP Sample

```
<?php

$re = '/[-, \/:]/';
$str = '2000-11-11 12-12-13';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remain only numbers use `\D` - is not a number

```
str_replace(' ', '', preg_replace('\D', null, $row['acctstarttime']));
```

if months you want to preserve month names use `\W` - is not a letter(letters is letters, number and '_')

```
str_replace(' ', '', preg_replace('\D', null, $row['acctstarttime']));
```